# ImageView findViewById and setContent(R.layout.main) doesn't work

Tags: android, imageview, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with this simple code. I'm trying everything possible, but setContent(R.layout.main) always causes an error. If I tried debug code svgView = (SVGView)findViewById(R.id.svgview) value was always null.

This is my code:

SVGViewActivity.java :

```
    package android.svgview;

    import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
    import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class SVGViewActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SVGView svgView;
    private ViewListener viewListener;
    private ViewState viewState;
    private SVG svg;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        svgView = (SVGView)findViewById(R.id.svgview);
        viewListener = new ViewListener();
        viewState = new ViewState();

        svgView.setViewState(viewState);
        svgView.setOnTouchListener(viewListener);
        viewListener.setViewState(viewState);

        svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android);
        svgView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        svgView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    }
}
```

SVGView.java

```
package android.svgview;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SVGView extends ImageView implements Observer {

    private ViewState viewState;

    public SVGView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setViewState(ViewState viewState){
        if(this.viewState==null){
            this.viewState = viewState;
            this.viewState.addObserver(this);
        }
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        canvas.scale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        canvas.translate(viewState.getX(), viewState.getY());

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        invalidate();

    }
}
```

and main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.svgview.SVGView
        android:id="@+id/svgview" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I change `svgView = (SVGView)findViewById(R.id.svgview);` for `svgView = new SVGView(this);` and then `setContentView(R.layout.main);` for `setContentView(svgView);` everything works fine. But using main.xml causes errors.

I tried clean and recompile project, compile it in new eclipse instalation with all updates but no effect. I have no idea where is a problem :-/

Comment: Please include the errors that you are receiving - ideally a stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to supply this contructor in your `SVGView.java`:

```
public SVGView(Context context AttributeSet atrs ) {
    super(context, atrs);
}
```

Then change the declaration in your xml-file to this:

```
<android.svgview.SVGView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/svgview" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything runs great. Can you please explain me, why this constructor

    public SVGView(Context context AttributeSet atrs ) {
        super(context, atrs);
    }

solved my problem? :)

Comment: The `AttributeSet` parameter contains stuff like witdh and height supplied in your XML-file. It's the one that will be called when a widget is added through xml. I could possibly also solve the problem by setting the LayoutParams for SVGView in the constructor. (If my answer solved your problem, please accept it as answer.)

Answer (score 0):

add constructor

```
public SVGView(Context context, AttribeSet attributeSer)
 {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything runs great. Can you please explain me, why this constructor

    public SVGView(Context context AttributeSet atrs ) {
        super(context, atrs);
    }

solved my problem? :)

Comment: because when we add any widget from layout ,it calls related java class of frameWork with constructor(context, AttributeSet) where attributeSet helps in reading all the properties like width,height,background etc . for example button will call Button.java .